# Сохранение в Blob-поля в FireBird (на Delphi)

Tags: delphi, firebird

как осуществить сохранение в blob-поля zip-файла (да я знаю что так лучше не делать, но надо всё таки). 
Если в вкратце то нужно закачать один небольшой архив в blob-поле в базе Firebird. Насколько я помню это делается через поток вроде даже через BlobStream но как точно не помню. можете показать как или пример показать.

Comment: через потоки. на ibase.ru погляди

Comment: Давал ответ на похожий вопрос [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/472492/2110), может информация пригодится

Answer (score 4):

```
DataSet.Append; // или Edit - Открыть датасет для редактирования 
TBlobField(Dataset.FieldByName('Имя вашего поля')).LoadFromFile('Полное имя вашего файла');
DataSet.Post; // Сохранить изменения
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
var
Stream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  Stream := nil;
  try
    Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    DS.edit;
    TBlobField(DS.FieldByName('fieldname')).SaveToStream(Stream);
    DS.post;
  except
    Stream.Free;
  end;
  Stream.Free;
end;
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: несколько странное поведение будет в случае возникновения исключения, деструктор будет вызван дважды