# Взять изображение через OpenDialog и записать в Blob-поле БД FireBird 2.5 - delphi

Tags: delphi, firebird, lazarus

Необходимо брать картинки через opendialog и по нажатию на кнопку записывать файлик в `blob`-поле базы `Firebird`. В отсутствии должного опыта не могу сообразить и подправить код для себя (в тех примерах которые видел). На сколько я понял все стоит делать через поток, а эта тема особенно дремучая для меня ... Кому не сложно, подскажите

```
    IBQuery2.Open; 
    IBQuery2.Active:=false; 
    IBQuery2.Edit; 
    IBQuery2.SQL.Add('insert into MainTable (img) VALUES (?img)'); 
    (IBQuery1.FieldByName('IMG') as TBlobField).LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName);
    IBQuery2.Active:=true; 
    IBQuery2.ExecSQL;
```

IBQuery1 имеет запрос на выборку всех полей, т.е. он отображает мне все что надо при запуске приложения. IBQuery2, запрос в нем не прописан, использую его для задания запроса на создания новой строки в базе, а дальше по задумке в Blob-поле надо записать картиночку.

Использую стандартные компоненты Delphi 7 - с вкладки Interbase, Lazarus - с вкладки SQLdb

**delphi 7 / lazarus**

Comment: покажите как вы сами старались?

Comment: в вопросе нажмите **править** и добавьте код в вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем варианте много все лишнего.

```
//IBQuery2.Open; 
//IBQuery2.Active:=false; 
//IBQuery2.Edit; 
IBQuery2.SQL.Add('insert into MainTable (img) VALUES (?img)'); 
(IBQuery1.FieldByName('IMG') as TBlobField).LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName);
//IBQuery2.Active:=true; 
IBQuery2.ExecSQL;
```

IBQuery2.SQL.Add - если в IBQuery2.SQL был запрос, тогда ваш запрос дополнится и получится каша. Я использую IBQuery2.SQL.Text, тогда не будет таких ситуаций.

И при выполнении вставки данных - нужно использовать ParamByName, а FieldByName используется в случаях когда выбраны данные.

?img - там точно параметры через ?(знак вопроса задаются), а не : (двоеточие) - :img

Вы можете сделать выборку данных и отредактировать img поле, но в таком случае у вас должны быть данные в таблице MainTable. Результат будет примерно таким:

```
if OpenDialog1.Execute Then
begin
  IBQuery2.SQL.Text := 'Select img ... where id='
  IBQuery2.Edit;
    (IBQuery1.FieldByName('img') as TBlobField).LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName);
  IBQuery2.Post;
end;
```

Или попробовать добавить данные, в таком случае получится что то такое:

```
if OpenDialog1.Execute Then
begin
  IBQuery2.SQL.Text := 'insert into MainTable (img) VALUES (:img)'; 
  IBQuery1.ParamByName('img').LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName, ftblob);
  IBQuery2.ExecSQL;
end;
```

PS: Писал "в слепую" так что код только приближает к правильно ответу.

Comment: **Спасибо большое!** Это как раз то, что нужно и самое главное все оказалось так просто...сравнил со своими наработками, где-то рядом бродил, а до истины не добирался...теперь все в порядке! Смущает только то, что при просмотре базы через редактор, в блоб-поле у всех картинок поп-ап одинаковый, как будто имена файлов одинаковые..но мб это бредит сам редактор...на функционал программы не влияет... 2й вариант кода идеально подошел, как раз создаю новую запись, затем пишу или не пишу картинку, а потом остальные поля через запрос update забиваю текстом. наверное не профессионально, но работает =)

Comment: так можно в `Insert'е` указать все необходимые поля  и повторно не вызывать `update`.  `insert into MainTable (img, name,...) VALUES (:img, :name...)` и присвоить все параметры через ParamByName: `IBQuery1.ParamByName('name').Value := 'someName';`

Answer (score 0):

Там есть компонент TDBImage. Поместите его в интерфейс как поле БД и ... вперед.

Comment: нее, так не пойдет... в данном случае я пишу картинки, а если мне понадобиться писать доки или другие какие-то файлы? я хочу понять сам принцип, как брать через диалог и класть в блоб-поле базы...

Comment: http://www.devrace.com/ru/fibplus/articles/2261.php 

Это прочитайте